# print ASP.NET page with colors

Tags: asp.net, printing

How can i allow printing my ASP.NET page (containing GridView,Buttons, and DropDownList)
with the colors ? that for colored report table.

Comment: This is not something in your control. If the browser is showing the page in color, then the printing driver and printer are what will decide how it comes out.

Comment: Is this IE8?  If so check the tools last tab option for printing color: http://www.febooti.com/support/faq/iezoom/print-web-page-background.html

Comment: If you need to support a wide variety of browsers and want to control output, then you should think about putting the output into a PDF or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

The color of print output is relative to your printer and also HTML tag setting. if a page in browser show all the colours then printer can print it or stop it as per the configuration of printer. also you can manage the background and image print property on printer properties that help you to get desired result.